# Use Scipy sparse matrices for Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pygame, conways-game-of-life

These days I've been trying to make Conway's Game of Life in Pygame. It is finished by now and it works well, but I didn't want to limit myself to run the game with a small grid, so I decided to try something like a 274x147 grid (so it almost fills the entire screen). The problem is that, with python normal "matrices" (arrays of arrays) it worked incredibly slow. After doing some reading, I came to the conclusion that it was a better idea to use Numpy matrices, but after doing that, nothing changed significantly. Doing further research, I stumbled across Scipy sparse matrices, which fitted perfectly in the project because in the game of life the matrix is sparse most of the time, but when I tried to implement them in the code, the FPS dropped significantly, even when I wasn't iterating through them. Why is this? Any advice to help me optimise my code?

I attach my main script here:

````
import math
import numpy
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import pygame.math as m
from text import Text
from button import Button
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

drawing = False
erasing = False
started = False
timer = False
time_since_last_iter = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game of Life")
icon = pygame.image.load("res/icon.png")
cell_img = pygame.image.load("res/cell.png")
font = pygame.font.Font("res/arcadeclassic.ttf", 32)
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

bg = pygame.image.load("res/grid.png")
fps_txt = Text(screen, (255, 255, 255), font, m.Vector2(10, 10)) #Fps text object, so I can see how's the game running
button = Button(screen, m.Vector2(screen.get_width() - 110, 10), m.Vector2(100, 30), (95, 95, 95), (80, 80, 80), "Run") #Button to start the game

mat_dim = (274, 147)

cell = sparse.lil_matrix(mat_dim, dtype=bool)
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    mp = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pos = m.Vector2(mp[0], mp[1])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and button.check_pos(mouse_pos):
                started = True
            elif not started:
                if event.button == 1 and not button.check_pos(mouse_pos):
                    drawing = True
                elif event.button == 3 and not started:
                    erasing = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and not started:
            if event.button == 1:
                drawing = False                          
            elif event.button == 3:
                erasing = False

    if not started:
        if drawing:
            if mouse_pos.y >= 50:                  
                grid_mouse_y = mouse_pos.y - 50
                cell[int(mouse_pos.x / 7), int(grid_mouse_y / 7)] = True
        elif erasing:
            if mouse_pos.y >= 50:                  
                grid_mouse_y = mouse_pos.y - 50
                cell[int(mouse_pos.x / 7), int(grid_mouse_y / 7)] = False

    global_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if global_time - time_since_last_iter > 200:
        time_since_last_iter = global_time
        timer = True

    if started:      
        global_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if global_time - time_since_last_iter > 200:
            time_since_last_iter = global_time
            timer = True

        if timer:     
            next_matrix = sparse.lil_matrix(mat_dim, dtype=bool)       
            for i in range(mat_dim[0]):
                for j in range(mat_dim[1]):
                    neighbours = 0                
                    # Neighbour count
                    for s_i in range(-1, 2):
                        for s_j in range(-1, 2):
                            try:
                                if cell[i + s_i, j + s_j] and not (s_i == 0 and s_j == 0):
                                    neighbours += 1
                            except IndexError:
                                continue

                    if cell[i, j]:
                        if neighbours > 3 or neighbours < 2:
                            next_matrix[i, j] = False
                        else:
                            next_matrix[i, j] = True

                    elif neighbours == 3:
                        next_matrix[i, j] = True
                    else:
                        next_matrix[i, j] = False

            for i in range(mat_dim[0]):
                for j in range(mat_dim[1]):
                    if not next_matrix[i, j] and cell[i, j]:
                        cell[i, j] = False
                    elif next_matrix[i, j] and not cell[i, j]:
                        cell[i, j] = True

            timer = False

    for i in range(mat_dim[0]):
        for j in range(mat_dim[1]):
            if cell[i, j]:
                screen.blit(cell_img, (i * 7, j * 7 + 50))

    button.draw(mouse_pos)

    clock.tick()  
    fps_txt.draw("fps       " + str(math.ceil(clock.get_fps())))

    pygame.display.update()```
````

Comment: Neither `numpy` arrays or `lil` is optimized for that kind of cell by cell access. A plain python dictionary with `(i,j)` tuple keys might be better.

Comment: `dok` is a dictionary subclass, not `lil`.  But `dok` has extra baggage compared to `dict`.  `lil` and `dok` are better than `csr` or `coo` for element access, but that doesn't they are best.

Comment: @hpaulj So you recommend me implementing my own dictionary?

Comment: No, use the Python dictionaries.  But your original list of lists may be as good as it gits.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, I meant python dicts. So you say there's no way to handle such big matrices?

Comment: You aren't the first to attempt this game in Python.  See the tags.

Comment: @hpaulj  I know, but I wanted to know how large I could make the grid. Thanks for your help!